# Selenium Javascript: Check if element matches By-object

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Given a `WebElement` and a `By` object is it possible to find out if the element matches this `By`-object?
The function should return true or false.

e.g.

```
foo(myWebElement, By.className("myClass myClass2"));
foo(myWebElement, By.css("div"));
foo(myWebElement, By.id("idA"));
```

I am trying to write a function which given a `WebElement` and a `By`-object should return the first parent element that matches the `By`-object. This is what I have so far but the `doesElementMatch` function is missing:

```
const findParentElement = async (current, by) => {
  try {
    do {
      element = await element.findElement(By.xpath("./.."));
    } while (!doesElementMatch(element, by);

    return element;
  } catch (e) {
    // reached top of DOM
    return null;
  }
}
```

If you have another solution for this problem I would be happy too.

Comment: Did you figure anything out on this?

Comment: I did not but I solved the problem I had so that the function in the question was not needed anymore... I'll write an answer

Comment: @David please write a comment under the answer if it did not help you. Maybe you can explain why you need to check if an element matches a By-object and we can find a other/better solution. Because I don't think the function we were looking for exists.

Comment: I've posted my own answer for what I managed to figure out, and explained why yours didn't work for my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an answer to this question yet but I solved my problem anyways. I'll share it here, maybe it will help.

### Wrong Idea

My idea was to find all elements that have a parent that matches the given By-selector, e.g. a ´p´ that has a `div` with class `myClass` as a parent.

My approach was to firstly select the child element and then check if it has a certain parent using the function from the question.

### Working approach

It is better to firstly select all parent elements that match the `By`-selector and then go through each of them to find the child element. e.g.

```
let parents = await driver.findElement(By.css("div.myClass"));
for (let i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
  let child = await parents[i].findElement(By.css("p");
  if (child)
    return child;
}
```

### Other working approach

It is also possible to do the above using only css-selectors with the character `>`. e.g. `div.myClass>p`. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by [IceRevenge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67183754/1940394) didn't work for me because I can't pre-filter my top level elements. I'm working against a [bug in FireFox](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1711#issuecomment-689591214) where you can't get the root shadowDom element without an error, so you have to get the whole list of children.

This is what I came up with. It's not ideal, but also not horrible.

```java
private <T> T noSuchElementNull(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    try {
        return supplier.get();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

private WebElement getMatchingShadowDomChild(
        final List<WebElement> children,
        final Function<WebElement, Boolean> topLevelSearch,
        final Function<WebElement, WebElement> grandChildSearch,
        final String errorMessage
) {
    Optional<WebElement> child = children.stream()
            .filter(topLevelSearch::apply)
            .findFirst();
    if (child.isPresent()) {
        return child.get();
    }

    Optional<WebElement> grandChild = children.stream()
            .map(c -> noSuchElementNull(() -> grandChildSearch.apply(c)))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .findFirst();

    return grandChild.orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException(errorMessage));
}
```

Then I can use that in pretty cleanly for most uses cases like this:

```java
private List<WebElement> getShadowDomChildren(final WebElement rootElement) {
    return (List<WebElement>) ((JavascriptExecutor) browser.getWebDriver())
            .executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot.children", rootElement);
}

private WebElement getInnerShadowElementByTagName(final WebElement rootElement, 
                                                    final String tagName) {
    List<WebElement> children = getShadowDomChildren(rootElement);
    return getMatchingShadowDomChild(
            children,
            c -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getTagName(), tagName),
            c -> c.findElement(By.tagName(tagName)),
            String.format("Unable to find an inner element with TagName=[%s]", tagName));
}
```

Comment: So you are basically looping through an array and looking for the one that matches your function right? Seems like a good solution to me, can‘t think of anything better

Comment: Yeah, directly check the top level children, and of those don't find anything, then check all dependents accordingly.